# Can you use an existing array in the left side of a deconstruction

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

With Google apps script releasing their V8 engine with ES6 support, I was taking myself through an ES6 course.  On the subject of deconstruction I thought of the following scenario that I use in my current code quite frequently.

```
function oldStyle() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues()
  var headers = data.shift() //[id, first_name, last_name, email, gender]
  data.forEach(function (row){
   console.log(row[headers.indexOf('first_name')]+" "+row[headers.indexOf('last_name')]) 
  })
}
```

Using this allows for the columns to be in any order in the spreadsheet, moved etc and the code will still work (obviously they can't be renamed being the downside).

When going through the training page on array deconstruction I immediately thought I could use my headers variable as the left side of a deconstruction so I could really quickly reference columns with minimal code.

```
function es6() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  const data = ss.getDataRange().getValues()
  const headers = data.shift() //[id, first_name, last_name, email, gender]
  data.forEach(function (row){
    // Use the headers variable as the left side of destructuring instead of the working line 20
    // let headers = row or
    // let [headers] = row
    // the idea being it's really quick to merge/reference based on column headings
    let [ ,first_name, last_name] = row //instead of having to type the column position in the array
    console.log(`${first_name} ${last_name}`)
  })
}
```

Having tested this I understand why the commented code doesn't work.  My question is therefore is there a way to make it work? Or a more efficient way of doing what I do with `row[headers.indexOf('first_name')]`

Comment: Just use `let [id, first_name, last_name] = row`. You don't need to reference `id`.

Comment: @DimuDesigns I don't need to reference id and I haven't. Note I used a comma to discard the first item.

Comment: Side note: Rhino(oldStyle) supported array deconstruction.

Comment: @GH5000x I just tested it using a preceding comma to discard the first item and it worked for me. Do you have V8 enabled?

Comment: Yes @DimuDesigns.  the uncommented code is working.  I am asking if there is a way for the existing headers array to be used in the left side of a deconstruction as per the question title.

Comment: I don't think what you want to do is possible. You want to use the array values of the header as variable names for the rows. What happens if the header column name has a space in it? You'd have to use a complex eval function and that would just get ugly.

Comment: I would re-ask this question without the GAS context since technically its not a GAS specific question. You want to do `var a = ["one", "two", "three"]; ....something... = [an array of length 3];` and then have `one = [the first value]; two = [the third value]; ...`